# PL/SQL Cartesian Join

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL and I am using version 10.0.6.1796
Can you tell me if there is a way to check to see if my query has a Cartesian join?

Can this be displayed when enabling warnings?

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Show us your stored procedure. Also there is no Version 10.0.6.1796 of "PL/SQL". And there never was an Oracle 10.0 release. There was only Oracle 10.1 and Oracle 10.2

Comment: If you use explicit `join` syntax, rather than the old implicit syntax where you have comma-separated tables in the `from` clause, you will find it much harder to accidentally generate a cartesian product. Also, version 10 of what; is that referring to the PL/SQL Developer client?

Comment: The [`plsql`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) tag is for the Oracle PL/SQL programming language. If your question is about [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) the third party IDE, then please use the [`plsqldeveloper`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsqldeveloper/info) tag instead.

Comment: If you're using PL/SQL Developer you can select the query you're interested in (just clicking somewhere in the text of the query is fine) and then hit F5, which will bring up an Explain Plan window on the query. Then look for a MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN line, as suggested by @Aleksej in his answer. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the explain plan:

```
SQL> select * from tab1 a, tab1 b;

no rows selected


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2439298300

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |             |     1 |    26 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN|             |     1 |    26 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN    | SYS_C008913 |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   BUFFER SORT        |             |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    INDEX FULL SCAN   | SYS_C008913 |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```